# Sharepoint 2013 Discussion list webpart access denied

Tags: web-part, discussion-board

I'm facing issues with forum discussion. I'm trying to add one in my page. I did the following steps:

-Go to Site Contents and add a new Discussion Board list.
-Create a discussion
-Go to the page where I want to add the discussion list
-Add a webpart in that page. Apps > Discussion list

When I go to my page, the webpart is created but not with the new discussion I created earlier, and also when I'm trying to click "new discussion" to add one I'm redirected to a page where they tell me that access is denied.

Answer (score 0):

The steps you mentioned are correct. Make sure you have sufficient rights in the site/subsite where you are adding the discussion board webpart.

To identify if you have added the correct discussion board and not something else, hover your mouse over the ***"new discussion"*** link and see the URL at the footer of the page.

The steps you followed works fine for me.

[image]